# How to add a column with sequential values that expands a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a column `time_bin` that is based on cumulative radiocarbon dates. However I need to fill the gaps in the `time_bin` sequence. In the example data below this means I need 2700, and 3100 added in. This will be applied to a lot of different data sets with different gaps so needs to be automated. It will have to expand this size of the dataframe, its fine if the values in the other columns are just NA for now as I think I know how to populate them with what I need once they're created.

The `time_bin` column is created by using `mutate` along with `ceiling` as shown below, so maybe it can be changed at this point, rather than later.

I can create the column I need,called `seq` below, but I'm not sure how to force it into a dataframe.

If there's a way this can be done with a tidyverse aproach rather than vectored as I have done it that would be great too.

So far I have:

```
data<- structure(list(cumulative.time = c(2458.09948930625, 2580.22242330625, 
                                          2707.31373980624, 2839.71214840625, 2977.77505230625, 3121.87854830625
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

data <- data%>% mutate(time_bin=ceiling(cumulative.time/100)*100)

max <- max(data$time_bin, na.rm = TRUE)

min <- min(data$time_bin, na.rm = TRUE)

seq <- seq(from = min, to = max, by = 100)
```

Thanks people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to create a sequence between minimum of `time_bin` value till maximum with a step of 100.

```
tidyr::complete(data, time_bin = seq(min(time_bin), max(time_bin), by = 100))

# time_bin cumulative.time
#     <dbl>           <dbl>
#1     2500           2458.
#2     2600           2580.
#3     2700             NA 
#4     2800           2707.
#5     2900           2840.
#6     3000           2978.
#7     3100             NA 
#8     3200           3122.
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks for such a quick reply but I get the following error with your answer: Error: Column name `time_bin` must not be duplicated.

Comment: Are you using it on the data that you have shared or some other data?

Comment: I've got it now, I was just being an idiot, was trying to run it piped but hadn't taken the second data out so it was runing data%>% complete(data,...) works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a join. If we make your `seq` variable into a data.frame, we can do the appropriate join with `data`.

```
library(dplyr)
seq <- data.frame(time_bin = seq(from = min, to = max, by = 100))
data %>% right_join(seq) %>% arrange(time_bin)
Joining, by = "time_bin"
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  cumulative.time time_bin
            <dbl>    <dbl>
1           2458.     2500
2           2580.     2600
3             NA      2700
4           2707.     2800
5           2840.     2900
6           2978.     3000
7             NA      3100
8           3122.     3200
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!